How to find response of DT system to an input
This year I have fallen behind in my Signals module due to poor mental health and insomnia. I have a homework due in 9 hours and dont understand anything, while also not having the time to learn everything. If anyone has time to help I would be forever indebted as this module is threatening my chances at passing first year.
Question:
DT System:
y[n] = 2y[n-2] + x[n] - 0.15y[n-1] - 0.7x[n-3]
a) “If this system is initially at rest, and then we input x[n]=u[n] - u[n-5] to it (u[n] is unit step function), find the response of this system to the input x[n].”
b) “Using only the basic building blocks: scaling, summation, and shift (delay or advancing) block, Sketch out this system’s block diagram.

Hi Lucy, I’m sorry to hear about your health. As a policy we don’t provide full answers to homework on here, but if you show at least some attempt to solve this yourself I’ll be glad to assist you! we can get this done in the next 9 hours ;)

@Jdip I have a totally off attempt:
y[0] = 2y[-2] + x[0] - 0.15y[-1] - 0.7x[-3]
0+1-0-0
=1 (when inputted at n=0 even though n=0 is at rest)
y[1]=2y[-1]+x[1]-0.15y[0]-0.7x[-2]
0+1-0.15-0
=0.85
y[2]=2y[0]+x[2]-0.15y[1]-0.7x[-1]
0+1-0.15(0.85) -0
=2.8725
y[3]=2y[1] + x[3] -0.15y[2]-0.7x[0]
2(0.85) + 1 -0.15(2.8725)-0.7
=1.5691
y[4]=2y[2]+x[4]-0.15y[3]-0.7x[1]
2(2.8725) + 1 - 0.15(1.5691) - 0.7
=5.8096
I made the false assumption that y[n] where n<0 is at rest due to dodgy python code, but i dont know how to do this without that assumption anyway due to [y-3] etc.

@Lucy: are you sure you quoted the question  correctly? The term $2y[n-2]$ makes the filter unstable and dealing with that seems beyond what would be asked with someone at your level.

@Jdip yup its 100% correct. We havent done any classwork with a system like this, our uni is just real bad for throwing questions like this at us with no prep!

@Lucy: Sorry, then I don't know how to help you. Without knowing what you already have covered in class specifically around stability I can't even guess what the expected answer should be. The question as posted has  no "standard" solution. Could be a misprint perhaps? Can you ask some of your classmates what they did ?

@Hilmar Im looking at my friends answer for the question but it looks incomplete.
Here is the most advanced of this question type we have done in class:
Determine the responses to the following systems to the inputs quoted, over the range
of values of  for which the inputs exist.
[] = [ − 2] + [ − 1]
[] = {−3, −2, 1, 1,2}
[] initially = -2
n= -2 -> 2
n=-2 ) y[-2]=y[-4]+x[-3]=-2+0 = -2
n=-1 ) y[-1]=y[-3]+x[-2]=-2-3= -5
n=0 ) y[0]=y[-2]+x[-1]=-2-2= -4
n=1 ) y[1]=y[-1]+x[0]=-5+1= -4
n=2 ) y[2]=y[0]+x[1]=-4+1= -3
y[n]={-2,-2,-5,-4,-4,-3}

@Hilmar And here is what my friend put for the question i was asking about:
x[n]=2y[n-2]+(u[n]-u[n-5])-0.15y[n-1]-0.7(u[n-3]-u[n-8])
if x[n]=0 when n<0
y[n]=2y[n-2]-0.15y[n-1]
when n>0, x[n]=1
y[n]=2y[n-2]+1-0.15y[n-1]-0.7+0.7 (im not sure why shes got -0.7+0.7 instead of just 0 from the unit step)
y[n]=2y[n-2]-0.15y[n-1]+1
Thats all she has down

You can certainly calculate the answer over a finite range of samples. But this only works if that range is specified. In you previous example the sentence "over the range of values of  for which the inputs exist" does this. But that doesn't seem to be the case for your current problem. If it were, this would be quite simple. Tip: draw the input signal an determine "the range where the input exists".

As mentioned in the comments, this feels like a bit of a trick question since the filter is unstable. We typically don't provide full answers to homework problems, but you appear to be in a bind and you definitely need a crash course in difference equations.
I will show how to calculate the first few samples of the response which may or may not be the expected answer to the question. This one of the rare cases where Excel is useful for illustrative purposes

Here is recipe.

Start with time step $n=-1$. Here all variables are zero.
Propagate your state variables to the next time step. For example $x[n-3]$ of the current time step is $x[n-2]$ from the previous time step (See the blue arrows in the table)
Execute the difference equation for the current time step. Multiply the current state values with the appropriate coefficients and add them up
Go back to step 2 and repeat as needed

In the table I've highlighted a section of the output so you can see how it propagates through the state variables. The same pattern shows up in y[n-1] and y[n-2] just one/two samples later.
You can do this easily in Excel, Python, Matlab or any other program that supports basic math operations. It's not all that hard.
Here is the issue with stability: You can see that the output gets quite large (>42 in step 10). It will continue to grow until it becomes infinite, hence there is not well-defined response.
